# button in html not rendering with jquery body object

Tags: jquery, html

When I insert a button in my html, it is not rendering. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the jquery body object I have. Would be really helpful if you can explain what is going on here and why the button will not display.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <button class="newTweets">More Tweets!</button>
    </div>

    <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var $body = $('body');
        $body.html('<h1></h1>'); //h1 tags before

        var index = streams.home.length - 1;
        while(index >= 0){
          var tweet = streams.home[index];
          var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
          $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
          $tweet.appendTo($body);
          index -= 1;
        }
      });

    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: `$body.html('...');` removes any previous set content in body, use `append()` or `prepend()` instead

Comment: @chewchew If we solved your problem, please consider marking one of the answers as 'accepted' using the gray checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [.html](https://api.jquery.com/html/) function replaces the body's html with your header tag. What you want is either [.prepend](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [.append](https://api.jquery.com/append/), to add to what is already there.

Example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <button class="newTweets">More Tweets!</button>
    </div>

    <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var $body = $('body');
        $body.prepend('<h1></h1>'); //h1 tags before

        var index = streams.home.length - 1;
        while(index >= 0){
          var tweet = streams.home[index];
          var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
          $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
          $tweet.appendTo($body);
          index -= 1;
        }
      });

    </script>
  </body>
```